# Social groups and guilds near the border of Taldor and Qadira

Tags: pathfinder-1e, golarion

Our new adventure starts near the border of Taldor and Qadira. Now I am looking for any social groups or guilds that come from this spot. I vague remember that the Dervish Dancers and the Ulfenguard are coming from there but cannot verify it anywhere. Can anyone help me out with information? An hint about what races live there would be great too.

I already searched the http://www.d20pfsrd.com page but could not find anything there.

Comment: @GMJoe - The information is not easy to find, I can't even seem to narrow down which book it might be in.  Given that Golarion setting information is spread all over the damn place, this is an extremely reasonable question to ask.

Comment: @JackLesnie Fair enough. I'd remove my downvote, but can't until the question is edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it depends how close to "this spot" you mean.  If you mean anything from Taldor and anything from Qadira, then sure enough, there's a bunch.

For a semi complete list, the [Pathfinder Wiki](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/) is usually the best source. The SRD does not have product identity because of OGL restrictions, but the Pathfinder Wiki summarizes the Golarion "fluff."

Here's the [Taldor Organizations](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Category:Taldor/Organizations) page (e.g. [Ulfen Guard](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Ulfen_Guard), [Lion Blades](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Lion_Blades)) and the [Qadira Organizations](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Category:Qadira/Organizations) page (e.g. [Cult of the Dawnflower](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Cult_of_the_Dawnflower)). There are many more that have been mentioned in passing. The whirling dervishes (Advanced Class Origins) aren't really an organization, just a type of devotion to Sarenrae that is found frequently in Qadira.